# Change Layout direction in Mono for Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, xamarin.android, right-to-left

How can I change the layout direction from ltr to rtl ?

Comment: could you explain more as what have you done so far??

Comment: I have style for Layout and I wanna set direction to all item in Layout to rtl same as title and ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using this code in Styles.xml`

```
<style name="DirectionR">
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
</style>

<style name="DirectionL">
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
</style>
```

`

Click here for more information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html

Answer (score 2):

Added in API level 19:

XML:

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"

android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

If you want to change it programmatically, you can use ViewCompat (added in version 22.1.0):

Left to right:

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(mView, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

Right to left:

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(mView, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat